# Make div disappear by animating to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

What I would like to do is that a user can swap through divs. This is my html:

```
<article id="realize" class="realizeBox">
    <div class="shown">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Realisations: <span>AGFA</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="centering">
            <aside class="left">
                <p>Maecenas laoreet est bibendum, dictum mi vel, cursus mi. Curabitur feugiat libero vitae lorem venenatis consequat. Donec luctus nisi cursus miet sapien blandit, quis congue massa tincidunt.</p>
            </aside>
            <aside class="right">
                <p>Maecenas laoreet est bibendum, dictum mi vel, cursus mi. Curabitur feugiat libero vitae lorem venenatis consequat. Donec luctus nisi cursus miet sapien blandit, quis congue massa tincidunt.</p>
            </aside>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div class="centering"> <a href="#" class="next"></a> <a href="#" class="prv"></a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshown">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Realisations: <span>TEST</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="centering">
            <aside class="left">
                <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
            </aside>
            <aside class="right">
                <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
            </aside>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div class="centering"> <a href="#" class="next"></a> <a href="#" class="prv"></a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

As you can see I have multiple divs in my article. The first div is shown. The second (and later on 3d, 4th, ..) have the class `notshown` that has the css `display:none;`.

I also have 2 buttons for each div:

```
<a href="#" class="next"></a> 
<a href="#" class="prv"></a>
```

This is the javascript linked to it:

```
$('.next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.realizeBox .shown').next().length > 0)
    {
        $('.realizeBox .shown').removeClass('shown').addClass('notshown').next().addClass('shown').removeClass('notshown');
    }
});

$('.prv').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.realizeBox .shown').prev().length > 0)
    {
        $('.realizeBox .shown').removeClass('shown').addClass('notshown').prev().addClass('shown').removeClass('notshown');
    }
});
```

When next is clicked I check if there is a next div. If yes then I add the class `notshown` to the **current div** and the **next div** gets the class `shown` and class `notshown` is **removed**.

Now this is really boring, just showing and hiding divs. How can I create an effect that the divs are animated right and left when I click on next and previous.

I've tried to do this with animate but no success. I'm really bad at javascript so I don't really know how to do this. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use css transition to achieve this.

lets assume (as you havent added it) that the css for the `notshown` and `shown` class is

```
.shown{
  opacity:1;
}

.notshown{
  opacity:0;
}
```

you can very easily have it animate in and out by adding

```
#realizeBox > div{
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  /* trigger GPU rather than CPU for animations just for the lulz */

  transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}
```

Comment: the css for notshown is display:none; as you can see in my topic. When I use opacity there is a white space beneath the div and I don't want that .. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refuse this answer if you'd like, but making a carousel from scratch is rather tedious, especially when there are many solutions to this issue that have already been coded and that you can modify.  here's several examples of what you're looking for: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});

<div class="slider1">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar2"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar3"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar4"></div>
</div>
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

css code to do so

```
@-webkit-keyframes disappear {
    from{transform: translate(0,0);}
    to{transform: translate(-100%,0);}
}
@keyframes disappear{
    from{transform: translate(0,0);}
    to{transform: translate(-100%,0);}
}    
.notshown{
    animation: disappear 2s;
    -webkit-animation: disappear 2s;
}
```

this will affect the div when the class add to it

after it's finished it will back to it's position

if you use `display:none` you won't see the affect ( it will move hidden )

so the way is to remove `display:none` from css and use `setTimeout` with delay time equal to time you use with `animation` to delay the hidden of the div till the animation finish

this the whole code (tested with chrome & firefox & IE 11)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".notshown").css('display','none');
        $('.next').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($('.realizeBox .shown').next().length > 0)
            {
                $('.realizeBox .shown').removeClass('shown').addClass('notshown').next().addClass('shown').removeClass('notshown');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".shown").css('display','');
                    $(".notshown").css('display','none');
                },2000);
            }
        });

        $('.prv').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($('.realizeBox .shown').prev().length > 0)
            {
                $('.realizeBox .shown').removeClass('shown').addClass('notshown').prev().addClass('shown').removeClass('notshown');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    @-webkit-keyframes disappear {
        from{transform: translate(0,0);}
        to{transform: translate(-100%,0);}
    }
    @keyframes disappear{
        from{transform: translate(0,0);}
        to{transform: translate(-100%,0);}
    }
    .notshown{
        animation: disappear 2s;
        -webkit-animation: disappear 2s;
    }

</style>
<a href="#" class="next">next</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="prv">prv</a>
<article id="realize" class="realizeBox">
    <div class="shown">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Realisations: <span>AGFA</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="centering">
            <aside class="left">
                <p>Maecenas laoreet est bibendum, dictum mi vel, cursus mi. Curabitur feugiat libero vitae lorem venenatis consequat. Donec luctus nisi cursus miet sapien blandit, quis congue massa tincidunt.</p>
            </aside>
            <aside class="right">
                <p>Maecenas laoreet est bibendum, dictum mi vel, cursus mi. Curabitur feugiat libero vitae lorem venenatis consequat. Donec luctus nisi cursus miet sapien blandit, quis congue massa tincidunt.</p>
            </aside>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div class="centering"> <a href="#" class="next"></a> <a href="#" class="prv"></a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshown">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Realisations: <span>TEST</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="centering">
            <aside class="left">
                <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
            </aside>
            <aside class="right">
                <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
            </aside>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div class="centering"> <a href="#" class="next"></a> <a href="#" class="prv"></a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```